# Is there a difference in authentication\authorization in Django and Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, authorization

I am learing Django and Django REST Framework for project

I recently added authorization/authentication in the Django project, and after that created API for the app, and for that I installed DRF.

Answer (score -1):

"The Django authentication system handles both authentication and authorization. Briefly, authentication verifies a user is who they claim to be, and authorization determines what an authenticated user is allowed to do. Here the term authentication is used to refer to both tasks."

Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/

To sum up, authentication is the way to recognize an user, authorization is the way you allow certains actions to your users.

Comment: Yep I know it, I meant if there are differences between DRF and Django. Because DRF creates API.